# Верстка css

Tags: вёрстка, css

Код html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="windows-1251">
<title>Мой пробник</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
</head>

<div id="main">

<div id="head">
Шапка сайта
</div>

<div id="login">
Панель управления:
Логин:<br>
Пароль:
</div>

<div id="menu">
Меню:
</div>

<div id="text">
...Содержание страницы...
</div>

<div id="footer">
Пробник FMS © 2014
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Код CSS

```
body {
        background: #f3f2f3;
        color: #000000;
        font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Times New Roman;
        font-size: 12px;
}

#main { 
        margin:30px auto;
        width:800px;
}

#head {

        background: #A9A9A9;
        width:800px;
        height:150px;
}

#login {
        background: #7CFC00;
        float:left;
        width: 150px;
}

#menu {
        background: #32CD32;
        float:left;
        width: 150px;
}

#text{  
        background: #FF0000;
        float:right;
        width:650px;

}
#clear {
        clear;both;
        }
#footer {
        background: #FF8C00;
        clear:both;     
        width:800px;
        height:28px;
        }
```

Получается блок "Меню" отображается справа (после панели управления). Как поставить ее ниже блока "Панель управления"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так. HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <header>Шапка сайта</header>

    <aside>
        <div id="login"> Панель управления: Логин: <br> Пароль: </div>
        <div id="menu"> Меню: </div>
    </aside>       
    <article> ...Содержание страницы... </article>

    <footer> Пробник FMS © 2014 </footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body { 
    background: #f3f2f3; 
    color: #000000; 
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Times New Roman; 
    font-size: 12px; 
}
#main { 
   margin:30px auto;
   width:800px;
}

header {
   background: #A9A9A9;
   width:800px;
   height:150px;
}

aside{
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
}
#login {background: #7CFC00;}
#menu {background: #32CD32;}

article{  
    background: #FF0000;
    margin-left: 150px;
    width:650px;
}

footer {
   background: #FF8C00;
   clear:both;    
   width:800px;
   height:28px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6avPR/

Answer (score 3):

> charset="windows-1251"

Все советуют utf-8 использовать. По вопросу: `float: left;` в этом блоке удалите

```
#menu {
    background: #32CD32;
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
}
```

В следующий раз используйте [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) для того, чтоб показать большие блоки кода.

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu {
        background: #32CD32;
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        width: 150px;
}
```

то есть

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">

<div id="head">
Шапка сайта
</div>

<div id="login">
Панель управления:
Логин:<br>
Пароль:
</div>
<div id="text">
...Содержание страницы...
</div>
<div id="menu">
Меню:
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<div id="footer">
Пробник FMS © 2014
</div>
</div>

#main { 
        margin:30px auto;
        width:800px;

}

#head {

        background: #A9A9A9;
        width:800px;
        height:150px;

}

#login {
        background: #7CFC00;
        float:left;
        width: 150px;

}

#menu {
        background: #32CD32;
        float:left;
        width: 150px;
        clear:both;

}

#text{  
        background: #FF0000;
        float:right;
        width:650px;

}
#clear {
        clear;both;
        }
#footer {
        background: #FF8C00;
        clear:both;     
        width:800px;
        height:28px;
        }
```